General purpose system integration tool for FPGA/ASIC system on chip design
Intel/Altera Quartus offers Platform Designer (formerly Qsys and SOPC Designer before that). Xilinx offers Block Designers in their Xilinx Vivado. Microsemi offer SmartDesign in their Libero SoC.
In all these tools we define interfaces on blocks that represent modules written in HDL. These interfaces could be things like AXI4 MM, AXI ST e.t.c. An interface encapsulates a whole bundle of wires into a single connection and we can then connect two opposite interfaces together e.g Master MM to Slave MM or Source ST to Sink ST. Each module appears as a block with connections that could be singletons like clock and reset or actual interfaces e.g AXI4 or Wishbone.
we can use a GUI (or command-line via TCL scripts) where all blocks of a system are connected together. Once the connections are made in the GUI we can generate RTL code for that system and then simulate or synthesize it. It is very neat.
My question is, is there a "general purpose" system integration tool similar to these ones, maybe an open source version?

hm, only know Vivado, but that isn't specific on the bus you connect. It knows about the type of bus, but when you define your own, you can connect as you wish. Open Source: ICEStudio comes to mind (no idea whether that is still active), but I think that is more restrictive in bus architecture.

The thing is, if I just need a system integration tool, what do I get? I could try and download one of these tools' free version but why should do I when I am writing RTL code that could eventually go into an ASIC as well?

couple of aspects: you're rarely designing for FPGA and ASIC at the same time – different standard cells, different default reset behaviours… so, you'd probably start in the toolchain that you want to use for your ASIC design. Synopsys/cadence/mentor graphics have tools.
